# lvalue And rvalue Return Types For Efficiency

Tags: c++, function, opencv, reference, copy-elision

### Update:

1. So, as per the comment by Jean, I have looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization/12953150#12953150). This is actually pretty close to the question I am asking. The only difference is that it deals with Classes explicitly (which `cv::UMat` undoubtedly is);

   > However, would the functional nesting I am trying to do with the return type still be valid? Would copy elision still occur, with the intended result?

---

### Problem

I am currently using OpenCV's `cv::UMat` object class and my co-worker wrote a function to do `cv::UMat` addition as follows:

```
UMat addUMats(UMat & M1, UMat & M2){
    UMat returnMat;
    add(M1, M2, returnMat);
    return move(returnMat);}
```

Now, this works great if I call this like so:

```
cv::UMat A = data1; 
cv::UMat B = data2; 
cv::UMat C = addUMats(A, B);
```

But, when I try to pass in the function as a parameter to the function, I get an "argument must be lvalue" type error. For example,

```
cv::UMat A = addUMats(addUMats(alpha, beta), addUMats(alpha, beta));
```

for any valid `cv::UMats`, `alpha, beta`.

### So Far

I did a little bit of [research](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and found out that `std::move(input)` explicitly returns a temporary of type rvalue. So, it makes sense that there is an error thrown.

I realize that I can fix this problem by first doing something like:

```
cv::UMat inputA = addUMats(alpha, beta);
cv::UMat A = addUMats(inputA, inputA);
```

Or, I could even do something like,

```
UMat addUMats(UMat & M1, UMat & M2){
    UMat returnMat;
    add(M1, M2, returnMat);
    return returnMat;}
```

in which case, it is my understanding that the line `return returnMat` will cause a deep(?) temporary to be copied.

### Question

So, I know that there may be some OpenCV dependent things going on here; like, maybe it is because the type UMat has some funky casting going on or such.

> But, in the general case, what is the best way to adapt functions *like* `addUmats` to be able to take a function as a call to the function?

I am going for the most efficient solution in terms of run-time. Also, I don't want this question to be limited to the OpenCV case; getting an answer for any type of function that uses the `std::move(input)` call would be appreciated.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @TonyTannous I understand this, but I think that the question still applies in either case (or at least I want it to :p).

Comment: Learn the basics before venturing into advanced territory. In most cases it doesn't matter and return by value (and value semantics in general) is a nice thing.

Comment: there's return data optimization in recent g++ versions which avoids the extra copy, you don't have to worry for that anymore.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Is there documentation on this?

Comment: I think you want to write a function that returns UMat & .

Comment: @RobertJacobs but you cannot return a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @phatty check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization?s=1|5.8908

Comment: @RobertJacobs Which was the goal with `return std::move(output)`.

Comment: `return std::move(...)` is if not always wrong almost always wrong.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the link! Check the update!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing some `const` in your function's input parameters. Try as follows:

```
UMat addUMats(const UMat & M1, const UMat & M2) {
    UMat returnMat;
    add(M1, M2, returnMat);
    return move(returnMat);
}
```

Might not be the only problem, but as it stands, your function cannot take temporary variables as input because it assumes they can be modified inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you return a local variable using `std::move` then you disallow compiler to perform a RVO (Return Value Optimization), this is because you are returning a reference to UMat which is not the same type as UMat, and standard requires the same type to be returned if compiler is to be allowed to perform RVO.

If compiler anyway chooses not to use RVO, then object being returned must be treated as an rvalue, so when RVO is permitted then either copy elision is used or std::move is implicitly applied.

Here:

```
cv::UMat A = addUMats(addUMats(alpha, beta), addUMats(alpha, beta));
```

problem is in that `addUMats` returns by value, and `addUMats` accepts a reference but to lvalue reference. The solution is to add rvalue version of addUMats:

```
UMat addUMats(UMat && M1, UMat && M2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did you see the update I added by chance? Would that work in-lace of your solution to add a `UMat addUMats(UMat && M1, UMat && M2)`?

Comment: Simply removing std::move should not change anything, try compiling it

Answer (score 1):

## Your problem

You cannot pass an rvalue into your function because that function specifically requires an lvalue (an `UMat&`).

Think of it this way : `addUMats`'s parameters could be changed inside the function. But when you do `addUMats(addUMats(alpha, beta), addUMats(alpha, beta));`, you are calling `addUMats` on two temporary values that you will not be able to access later.

---

## Possible solution

Conceptually, adding two matrices A and B should not change either A nor B. So, if you are sure your colleague will not change A nor B inside the function, they could change the function's signature to :

```
UMat addUMats(const UMat & M1, const UMat & M2)
```

In that case, problem solved! You will be able to call `addUMats` on two temporary objects. Since they will not change anyway, it doesn't matter.

If you need an optimized code and take advantage of rvalue optimizations, you could also overload the function with:

```
UMat addUMats(const UMat && M1, const UMat && M2)
```